# Warning: imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {pop3.live.com:995/pop3}INBOX li

Tags: php, imap

Warning: imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {pop3.live.com:995/pop3}INBOX in /var/www/test.php on line 3 Notice: Unknown: Connection failed to pop3.hot.glbdns.microsoft.com,995: Connection timed out (errflg=2) in Unknown on line 0

I'm getting that error from this code...

```
<?php

$mailbox = imap_open ("{pop3.live.com:995/pop3}INBOX", "ravnizzle@live.com", "password");

?>
```

Comment: "Connection timed out" suggests there may be a configuration issue with your server

Comment: For example, this port is commonly firewalled on shared hosting....  Have you tried doing a basic connectivity test?  telnet pop3.live.com 995....

Comment: It's not shared hosting and what do you mean by basic connectivity test?